# jQuery event not raised in Gridview TH

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview that fill it with some data.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:GridView>
```

code:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dc.Regions.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I want when I clicked on `TH` section an alert showed.I wrote this code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#GridView1 th').on("click", function () {
        alert("nima");
     });   
</script>
```

but it doesc not work.where is my mistake?

thanks

---

**Edit 1)**
I Edit main question and add `'` for selector.I forgot to type that.
the problem is when I write this code it works.I want to know on does not work:

```
$('body').live('click','#GridView1 th', function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
```

Comment: you're using `live` why? is the grid appended after the page is loaded?

Comment: no no dear friend.It exist on my page.I know it is strange.but can you test it on your own page please?

Comment: copy paste your HTML code (after the page is rendered) into pastebin.com or jsbin.com for example so we can have something to test.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qpkVvNUT . I delete view state hidden input

Comment: edited my answer to include your current problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**are you sure you're writting** `$(#GridView1 th)`? should be at least `$('#GridView1 th')`... and check the View Source to see if the correct ID as if it's nested in other ASP.NET control will never be `GridView1`...

to be safe in any ASP.NET control you should use the `ClientID` property, so you can always write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var grid = '<%= GridView1.ClientID %>';
    $("#" + grid + " th").on("click", function () {
        alert("hello");
     });   
</script>
```

And **verify** in your source code if you actually have a Table Header `<th>` as I know It was optional in the `GridView` earlier days...

From your code, you just forgot that the script will run as soon is it on the page and mostly when the table code is not even there...

change this:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#GridView1 th').on('click', function () {
        alert("nima");
    });  
</script>
```

into this

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#GridView1 th').on('click', function () {
          alert("nima");
       });  
    });
</script>
```

or simply append your script code at the end of the page, so when the browser reach that line, all the others are already rendered and available to the DOM.

Here is a Live Example of your code: http://jsbin.com/etamug/edit#javascript,html simply click the **Render** button to see everything up and running...

I have used `$(function() {});` as a shortcut, but the original method is the one I have specified in this answer.

You can **find more information** regarding `$(document).ready()` in [jQuery website](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)